# SwiftUI hide TabView when clicking Logout with Firebase

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I a simple app with a Firebase Login/Logout. Login works perfectly and my app shows up when I logout the LoginView appears, but the problem is the TabView stays and you can just navigate to another tab. So what should happen: The tab bar should be invisible/hidden or my LoginView should appear over everything else.

**ContentView.swift**

```
    var body: some View {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            LoginView()
        }
        else {
            AppView()
        }
    }
```

**AppView.swift**

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        PlacesView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")
                Text("Places")
            }
        MeetupsView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.3")
                Text("Meetups")
            }
        ProfileView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                Text("Profile")
            }
        SettingsView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                Text("Settings")
            }
    }
}
```

**LoginView.swift**

```
@State var signInSuccess = false

var body: some View {
    return Group {
        if signInSuccess {
            AppView()
        }
        else {
            LoginFormView(signInSuccess: $signInSuccess)
        }
    }
}
```

**Settings Logout**

```
NavigationView {
            if !signedIn {
                ContentView()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
            else {
            List {
    Button(action: {
                    do {
                      try Auth.auth().signOut()
                        signedIn.toggle()
                    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                      print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
                    }
                    
                }){
                Text("Sign out")
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title2/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
          }
     }
```

Looks Like [image: this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ContentView` won't know how to trigger an update to the view hierarchy because at the moment, it has no way of understanding that Auth.auth().currentUser has changed values when the user logs out.

One solution is to use an @ObservableObject and Firebase's auth state listener to handle this for you:

```
class AuthManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false
    
    private var authStateHandle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init() {
        authStateHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { _, user in
            self.isLoggedIn = user != nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in ContentView:

```
struct ContentView : View {
  @ObservedObject var authManager = AuthManager()
  var body : some View {
    if authManager.isLoggedIn {
      AppView()
    } else {
      LoginView()
    }
  }
}
```

The nice thing about the auth state listener handle provided by Firebase is it handles hooking up to the global Auth() instance automatically, so you don't even need to worry about connecting it to your login or sign out functions. This means that you can probably remove the `signInSuccess` boolean check on your login view, since now that'll be handled at the `ContentView` level.